# Regxr: Select pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm new to a regular expression. How can I select a pattern like `data-v-**=""`from a string?

Here is my code is to match that pattern: `data-v-.+"$`, but it's not working. Can anyone help me to fix it?

Example String:

`<div data-v-41dfcbba="" class="aaaaaa" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><div data-v-fc1d9bbe="" data-v-41dfcbba="" style="height: 100%;"><div data-v-0392e45a="" data-v-fc1d9bbe="" class="example-class">`

**Expected result:**

```
data-v-41dfcbba=""
data-v-fc1d9bbe=""
data-v-41dfcbba=""
data-v-0392e45a=""
data-v-fc1d9bbe=""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
data-v-[^\s"]+="[^"]*"
```

- `data-v-` Match literally
- `[^\s"]+` Match 1+ times any char except a whitespace char or `"`
- `="[^"]*"` Match an equals sign, and from an opening till closing double quote

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7HTBFE/1)

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following.

```
data-v-[^=]*="[^"]*"
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/kNgy7Z/1)

***Explanation:***

- `data-v-`: Matching from data-v-: here.
- `[^=]*=`:  Matching everything till 1st occurrence of `=` then match 1st occurrence of =: here.
- `"[^"]*"`: Matching ", then matching everything till 1st occurrence of ", then matching ": here.